# How to store data in xml file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am new to javascript and using it my project.In that I need to read xml file and then after manipulating that I want to store the updated values back in xml file.I am getting the values from xml file successfully but not able to store the values back to xml file.
Here is the code I have tried.

```
        <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Hello
        </title>
    </head>
<body>
<script>
function loadXML()
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","data.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
//saving XML from document input fields
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Address")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = document.getElementById("address").value;
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Contact")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = document.getElementById("contact").value;
xmlDoc.save();
}

</script>
<form action="Display.html" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name :</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="name"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address :</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="address"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Contact :</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="contact"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="loadXML()"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help if anyone knows the answer.Please explain with example if possible
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You'll need some server side code to do the saving for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've fixed the code formatting in the question for you. Please take a moment to read the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the Ask a Question area, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. (There's also a preview box shown under the Ask a Question box where you can preview your question.)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery: you just use `$.ajax()` and send your data to something like `save_my_xml.php` via `POST`. There are some classes to work with XML in PHP, but if you get on well with Smarty I advise you to `fetch` your `xml_template.tpl` and then `file_put_contents`.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have to use pure javascript only to do the task.