# html / javascript on click write to file

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have only the most basic knowledge of web scripting, but i'm trying to learn something.
Here what I want to do:

I have a place in a server of my university and have a page there, id like to have some output of what happened in there. So i want to write into a file on click, which places in the same folder as html, also I would like to know how to open file at the end of it (like fstream::app in c++) and get system time.

Here's what I wrote:

```
<HTML>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">

function WriteFile() 
{
   var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
   var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("/net/my path/2011/rija9995/www/Test.txt", true); 
   fh.WriteLine("Some text goes here..."); 
   fh.Close(); 
}

</SCRIPT>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>title</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY VLINK=#FF0000 link=#FF0000 alink=#FF0000 bgcolor=#aaaa88 text=#FFFFFF>
<H6>
<TT><CENTER><h2>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
blah blah blah
<button id="button" type="text" onClick="javascript: WriteFile();" />x</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: by the way, i dont have much knoledge about systems, but the server runs linux i guess

Comment: you can't do that with straight JavaScript, but you can with PHP (which is really similar to C). The way to go would be HTML (javascript) --(notify of change, make request to) --> PHP script

Comment: JavaScript in websites is always executed on the client side. so if you want to write to a file on the server side you will need a server side language like, e.g.,  PHP.

Comment: i see, thanks, so how would i do that in PHP? and how to integrate php in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java script cannot have control on server side file system. You need to use a server side language instead i.e cgi-scripts/PHP/Java servlets etc. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557018/how-to-store-data-in-xml-file-using-javascript) for more details.

Comment: thats yet too comlicated for mee, i gues i just have to wait until i learn something new...

Comment: Is it possible to run an exe file instead in server side?

Comment: I am not much aware of running exe file but to run(call) .cgi (kind of executable script) is possible from JS, provided that script exist on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, thank you for your answers

```
<?php 
 $File = "file.txt"; 
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'a');
 $Data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data);
 fwrite($Handle, " <- "); 
 fwrite($Handle, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 $Data = "\n";  
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
 fclose($Handle); 
 ?>
```

although  i hadnt found how to call it upon buttonclick. Any ideas?